# Compile code in C to MIPS assembly

Tags: c, compiler-construction, assembly, mips

I wrote a C program that I need to see it in MIPS assembly code.

How do I install or operate a software that takes *.c file to be *.txt or *.something_else to see its MIPS assembly code ?

My OS is Linux.

Thanks a lot !!

BTW my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 128

int main ()

{
    char mychar , string [SIZE];
    int i;
    int count =0 ;  

    printf ("Please enter your string: \n\n");
    fgets (string, SIZE, stdin);

    printf ("Please enter char to find: ");
    mychar = getchar();

    for (i=0 ; string[i] != '\0' ; i++ )
        if ( string[i]  == mychar )
            count++;

    printf ("The char %c appears %d times\n" ,mychar ,count);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just write gcc -S in the console ? and what will it gives me ?

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood the question: I thought you could compile your code to the target platform. *comment deleted*

Comment: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Crossdev

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a MIPS cross-compiler, unless you're running Linux on a MIPS box, in which case you want a regular MIPS compiler. [Here](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/HOWTO/MIPS-HOWTO-9.html) is a howto for setting up a cross compiler on Linux.

Once you've compiled it, you'll want to see the MIPS disassembly. [objdump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) can help you there.

Comment: @C_guy: Bah, RPMS are evil. You can use [this](https://eng.ucmerced.edu/root01/SoE_April_07/ComputingSupport/il/collaboratory/collab-software/compilers-and-interpreters/mips-cross-compiler-package) to get a deb.

Comment: I going nuts of those cross compilers... I can't understand anything from those manuals... Is there a x steps to just convert a code from C to MIPS ?

Comment: Get a precompiled package from [CodeSourcery](http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/mips) if you can't build one yourself. They even have a package for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install a MIPS cross-compile library, and then you need to pass `-S` and one of the `-march=mips*` options to gcc.

Comment: Where I can find this directory ?

Comment: I have never heard about this. It sounds awesome. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dan Kegels' excellent and easy to use [cross-tool](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/) to compile your own MIPS cross compiler.

Comment: MIPSTOJAVA looks like it only takes a MIPS executable file and outputs Java.  Don't see anything in the docs about it converting C to MIPS source.